# Homogeneous Initial Value Differential Equation

Tags: differential

Im trying to solve this D.E:

$$(x^2-xy+y^2)dx+(-xy)dy=0, y(1)=0$$

After I subsituted $$y=ux$$
 $$dy=xdu+udx$$

I get
$$-ln(x)=ln(1-u)-1+u+c$$

Answer:
$$-xln(x-y)=y$$

assume () are absolute value

I truly appreciate everyone's help. I really do learn a lot from this website.

Comment: You've got the right answer.  Just plug back in $\frac yx$ for $u$ and simplify.

Answer (score 1):

After the substitution we get

\begin{align*}
&&x^2(1-u+u^2)dx-ux^2(xdu+udx)&=0\\[3pt]
\iff &&x^2(1-u)dx-ux^3du&=0 \\[3pt]
\implies &&\frac{dx}{x}+\left(1-\frac{1}{1-u}\right)du&=0\qquad x(1-u)\neq 0\\[3pt]
\implies &&\ln|x|+u-\ln|1-u|&=c\\[3pt]
\implies &&x\left(1-u\right)&=\pm e^{c-u}\\[3pt]
\implies &&x-y&=Ce^{-y/x}\qquad\text{where }C=\pm e^{-c}\\[3pt]
\end{align*}
From the initial condition we find $C=1$, and then
$$\boxed{\color{blue}{x-y=e^{-y/x}}}$$
Which is an implicit solution.